# Simulated "and" statement in grep that is not order specific

Tags: grep, regular-expression, bsd

I am trying to use a simulated "and" statement with egrep. Currently I have 
 egrep -i 'name.*policy'  which works only if the order of appearance is true. Alternatively, I can egrep -i 'name.*policy|policy.*name' .
I want to see if there is a better way to use an "and statement that is not order specific.

Comment: There isn't, use your solution or `grep name | grep policy`

Comment: Sorry yes it is duplicated for the most part. I was hoping to see if there was an improved way to use " egrep -i 'name.*policy' " that would not be order specific. Clearly there is not.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -P '(?=.*policy)(?=.*name)'
```

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately in my version of BSD, the -P option doesn't work.